# "'shared' is unavailable: Use view controller based solutions where appropriate instead" on App Extension

Tags: ios, swift, ios-app-extension

I have a class that makes a network call. I want to be able to use this class in both the main app and App Extension. However, in this class I use: `UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible`.

Since `shared` isn't available in App Extensions, is there a way that I can use something along the lines of `#available` such that I don't have to duplicate this class just because of that one line of code? (I could just remove the activity indicator but I rather not since I like to let users know when network calls are happening)

I've tried adding a pre-compiled Macro as suggested by an answer I found on another question, but the compile still complains.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use dependency injection pattern to refactor out the code depending on `UIApplication.shared`.

1. Use a protocol to describe the functionality that is currently provided by `UIApplication.shared`.
2. Implement that protocol for the base app, where `UIApplication.shared` is available and use it there. Implement another implementation without using `UIApplication.shared`, which would be used for app extensions.
3. Refactor your current class to use the protocol implementing objects and inject the proper implementation at the initialization (dependency injection pattern) - initializer of that class would accept a protocol implementation.
4. Wire up a proper implementation when creating an instance of the refactored class - in app extension pass it the implementation without `UIApplication.shared`, in base app the one with `UIApplication.shared`.

So e.g., Let's have this big class here:

```
class Big {

    ... a lot of code ...

    func a() {
        ... again some code ...

        // here the code that needs shared
        UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = true

        ... more code ...
    }
}
```

1. So first, a protocol:

   ```
   protocol NetworkIndicator {
       func showActivity()
   }
   ```
2. Then two implementations:

   ```
   class AppNetworkIndicator: NetworkIndicator {
        func showActivity() {
            UIApplication.shared.isNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible = true
       }
   }

   class ExtensionNetworkIndicator: NetworkIndicator {
       func showActivity() {}
   }
   ```
3. Refactor `Big` to support dependency injection:

   ```
   class Big {
       private let networkIndicator: NetworkIndicator

       init(networkIndicator: NetworkIndicator) {
           self.networkIndicator = networkIndicator
       }

       ... rest of code ...

       func a() {
           ... again some code ...

           // use injected protocol implementation
           networkIndicator.showActivity()

           ... more code ...
       }
   }
   ```
4. Finally, in the app, where you use the `Big` class, initiate it with:

   ```
   let big = Big(networkIndicator: AppNetworkIndicator())
   ```

   And in the extension, use the other implementation:

   ```
   let big = Big(networkIndicator: ExtensionNetworkIndicator())
   ```

Comment: i dont understand please. Am new and have this same problem

Comment: @DanielKabuAsare check the simple exampl